# Changing the label of required in text-field with react and material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am using Material-UI in react application. What I am trying to do is to change the label "Please fill out this field" of text-field when we set the required attribute.

I tried to use `setCustomValidity` with `inputProps`, but nothing happens. 
There are two types of this label. One is a tooltip that showed up when the mouse is hovered on the text-field, the other when we submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the 'required' validation message for the TextField component with a custom-validation message (when submitting the form) as follows:

```
     <TextField
        onInvalid={() => {
          document
            .getElementById("business-email-textfield")
            .setCustomValidity("Please type a valid email address");
        }}
        required
        id="business-email-textfield"
        label="Business Email"
        name="email"
        onChange={handleInput}
        variant="standard"
      />
```

In the handleInput function you should handle the input of course, but you should also reset the custom-validation message. For example:

```
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useReducer(
      (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    {
        email: "",
        businessType: "",
    }
  );

  const handleInput = (evt) => {
    const name = evt.target.name;
    const newValue = evt.target.value;
    setFormInput({ [name]: newValue });
    //the line below clears the custom-validatio message
    document.getElementById(evt.target.id).setCustomValidity("");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is not material-ui, but is the browser handling the error. This cannot be changed since the browser renders this based on the "required" attribute. You can only change this by doing custom error handling on your form.

Comment: The message can be changed with the  `setCustomValidity` method in the input element. But I cannot change it with the tex-field of Material-UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet which i used in my personal project:

```
<TextField
               error={this.props.error_val
                    ? true
                    : false
                }
                required={this.props.isRequired ? true : false}
                type={this.props.type}
                label={this.props.label}
                variant={this.props.VARIANT}
                className={classes.root}
/>
```

You can use `required` and  `error` attribute combination for deciding whether the input is filled or not.

Secondly, you can write a `validate()`  which is basically a `switch` statement where you will pass  "label name", "value" and put  the return value into your `<TextField/>` component.

Snippet:

```
    validate = (name, value) => {
        let error = "";
        switch (name) {
          case "name":
            error = (!value || value.length == 0) && "Please enter the name";
            break;
    }
            return error;
}
```

Comment: This is not the problem that I have, the label that I mentioned in my question is the one that will appear when you set the required attribute for you text-field, not the one that belongs to the material ui text-field prop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. I wanted to keep the `TextField` `required` prop to `true` because I wanted MUI to put the `Mui-required` CSS class where applicable in the component and its children. For example, you would get a nice red * next to the label.

So, you can wrap the `TextField` in a `Box` and put the `noValidate` prop on the `Box`, like this:

```js
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        required
        //...
      />
    </Box>
```

This will remove the native popup that came from the `required` prop and you can provide your own helper text.

p.s.: `autoComplete="off"` is needed to remove the nasty native autocomplete that "[provide automated assistance in filling out form field values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)"

Hope this helps.